# Fixing a USB 2.0 port in HP ENVY x360

Tags: usb, laptop

I have an HP 15-u011dx laptop and my devices have not been connecting to the USB 2.0 port properly. A device will only connect if the connector is held at a slight angle and if it's not plugged ALL the way in. They all work fine on the 3.0 ports so it is likely a hardware issue with the 2.0 port itself.

Here are pictures of the PCB containing the USB 2.0 port (as well as the headset jack and the volume control buttons):
HP ENVY x360 USB 2.0 board:

[image]

I was wondering if it was possible to re-solder the USB port to get it working again or maybe if I could get another one of these boards from HP, but I don't know the model number of this component.

Comment: It's not going to fit anywhere on SE. But your questions are simple. You can A, resolder the connection. B, replace the USB connector. Or C, Google the various numbers until your find a replacement part. Or look for for parts/not working on eBay and buy a broken envy 360 to take it's board out.

Comment: The part number is DA0Y61AB6D0 and you want the Rev. D version (rev=revision). If resoldering the USB connector and making sure the ribbon cable is connected properly does not work.

Comment: Just so everyone knows, my USB has been working perfectly since I put it back into my laptop. I guess maybe I misaligned it the last time I opened my laptop. Thanks for the advice, though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have the board taken out. That makes life a lot easier. I would start by sacrificing a USB cable and do continuity test on each wire. Alligator clip would help while you wiggle the port to test for lose.

If you can identify the wire or position that is loose, you can try fixing it with super glue or re-solder.

Answer (score 0):

From your description and the look of the board, it doesn't seem likely that the problem is related to loose soldering. Rather the problem is either with mechanical deformation/damage of connector contacts, or with contact contamination or wear, which is nearly impossible to repair.

If you want normal reliable USB connection, the best course of action would be to buy the entire add-on board from e-bay, or genuine [HP replacement part DA0Y61AB6D0](http://www.notebookparts.com/hp-pavilion-13-a000-13-a100-usb-board-da0y61ab6d0/).